# Table data overflows on zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, hammer.js

I have a table inside a `<div>`. The div contains a box ..

Now i have applied zoom feature to the table alone using an external plugin hammer.js.

So when i zoom my table, it overflows outside the box..Is there a way to sove this  issue ??

My div has the following css property to the box inside it :

```
.box {

    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(115, 165, 188, 0.52);
    border: 2px solid rgb(65, 65, 65);
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;

}
```

Comment: if you could paste jquery code plz.

Comment: You can shorten your border-radius to just `border-radius: 8px;`

Comment: @jai :Jquery code of what part?? Zooming ?? table ?? box ??

Comment: @sfjedi : thnk u bro..will be pleased if u can answer on my issue also !!